# How to find difference between table with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have exact two tables but some value differences. So I would like to find those differences with condition that if the column `value` has a difference of more than 10.

For example, all 9 columns have the same values in both tables, but the difference between the values column is 11, so this record is different. If the value difference is 9 so records are the same.

So I wrote this query to get differences:

```
select * 
from  test.test m 
inner join test.test1 t 
    on
m.month_date = t.month_date and  
m.level_1 = t.level_1 and
m.level_2 = t.level_2 and 
m.level_3 = t.level_3 and 
m.level_4 = t.level_4 and 
m.level_header = t.level_header and 
m.unit = t.unit and 
m.model_type_id = t.model_type_id and 
m.model_version_desc = t.model_version_desc 


where m.month_date = '2022-11-01' and abs(m.value - t.value)  > 10)
```

so this returns me all records that all column values are matched but did not pass the value difference condition.

Second, i have full outer join to get all differences

```
select  *
from  test.test m 
full outer join test.test1 t 
    on
m.month_date = t.month_date and  
m.level_1 = t.level_1 and
m.level_2 = t.level_2 and 
m.level_3 = t.level_3 and 
m.level_4 = t.level_4 and 
m.level_header = t.level_header and 
m.unit = t.unit and 
m.model_type_id = t.model_type_id and 
m.model_version_desc = t.model_version_desc 


where m.month_date is null  or t.month_date is null and  m.month_date = '2022-11-01'
```

How can I combine the results of these two queries without UNION? I want to have only one query (sub query is acceptable)

Comment: Can you share some data and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that for a given day, you need to find

- rows that match between the tables but exceed the `value` difference threshold

  **AND**
- rows present in either left or right table, that don't have a corresponding row in the other table

```sql
select  *
from  test.test m 
    full outer join test.test1 t 
        using (
         month_date,
         level_1,
         level_2, 
         level_3, 
         level_4, 
         level_header, 
         unit, 
         model_type_id, 
         model_version_desc )
where (m.month_date is null
       or    t.month_date is null
       and   m.month_date = '2022-11-01'  )
or    (m.month_date = '2022-11-01' and abs(m.value - t.value)  > 10);
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/c3zSO6m7)

Since the columns used to join the tables have the same names, you can shorten their list by swapping out the lengthy `table1.column1=table2.column1 and...` list of pairs for a single `USING (month_date,level_1,level_2,level_3,...)` [(doc)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM). As a bonus, it will avoid listing the matching columns twice in your output, once for the left table, once for the right table.

```sql
select * 
from (select 1,2,3) as t1(a,b,c)
    full outer join 
     (select 1,2,3) as t2(a,b,c)
        on t1.a=t2.a 
        and t1.b=t2.b 
        and t1.c=t2.c;
-- a | b | c | a | b | c
-----+---+---+---+---+---
-- 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3

select * 
from (select 1,2,3) as t1(a,b,c)
    full outer join 
     (select 1,2,3) as t2(a,b,c)
        using(a,b,c);
-- a | b | c
-----+---+---
-- 1 | 2 | 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. By combine I mean, combine results of two outputs of the above queries. 1st query returns matching records with given columns. But I filter out records that have differences in values of more than 10. so if all column values matched but the difference between value is 11 I want to see it in the final result. While the second query returns all rows that has differences in columns. so I want to merge results of these 2 queries without using the UNION. preferred 1 query with sub - query. I executed your query and it resulted on NULL for value column.

Comment: @Miko I set up a [test](https://dbfiddle.uk/7FC04UrR) and figured out what you mean by looking at the behaviour of your queries: it seems that you're looking for (rows that match between the tables but exceed the value difference threshold) and (rows present in either left or right table, that don't have a corresponding row in the other table). I updated my answer.

Comment: Note that `null` entries in your tables might complicate things if your `where` clause is based on an assumption that the column entry is `null` only because it has no corresponding record in the other table. If you permit `null` entries to exist in either of these tables to begin with, identical records that have a `null` in one or more columns will not be matched because `join` uses `=`, which will result in `null` rather than `true` when you do `null=null`. [See this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hFqvGk40) or [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/lNVFhgdI).

Answer (score 0):

In your first query, you can replace the null values for a specific number. Something like this:

```
    where m.month_date = '2022-11-01' and abs(ISNULL(m.value,-99) - ISNULL(t.value,-99))  > 10)
```

The above will replace the nulls for -99 (choose an appropriate value for your data), so if you have that m.value is 10 and t.value is null, then should be returned in your first query.

Comment: There's no `isnull()` in PostgreSQL. You can substitute it with a [`coalesce(m.value,-99)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) or a `case when m.value is null then -99 end`